# Test failing when using JaCoCO

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm trying to measure coverage using JaCoCo on this project: https://github.com/square/retrofit

Everything seems to work fine but, for some reason, several tests that used to work, fail when using JaCoCo runtime agent.

Here is (the interesting part) of my `pom.xml`:

```
...
<plugins>
   ...
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
         <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
         <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ...
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
      <executions>
         <!--
            Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
            is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
        -->
         <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <!--
                    Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                    for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                -->
               <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
         <!--
            Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
            unit tests have been run.
        -->
         <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
   ...
</plugins>
```

The complete `pom.xml` can be found here: https://pastebin.com/HSKJpS3g

All the tests are failing for the same cause, let me show an example.
Consider the class `Example` declared in this test:

```
@Test public void customMethodNoBody() {
    class Example {
      @HTTP(method = "CUSTOM1", path = "/foo")
      Call<ResponseBody> method() {
        return null;
      }
    }

    /* Do some operations with the class Example */
  }
```

Later in the code `Exemple.class` is passed to the method `TestingUtils.onlyMethod` which will throw an exception:

```
package retrofit2;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public final class TestingUtils {
  public static Method onlyMethod(Class c) {
    Method[] declaredMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    if (declaredMethods.length == 1) {
      return declaredMethods[0];
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("More than one method declared.");
  }
}
```

All the tests fail for this same exception being thrown, which wasn't happening before adding JaCoCo. Why is this happening ? How can I solve the problem ?

The command used by maven to run the tests is this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
-javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/root/retrofit/retrofit/target/jacoco.exec
-jar /root/retrofit/retrofit/target/surefire/surefirebooter7714471086789859732.jar
/root/retrofit/retrofit/target/surefire/surefire2679778491836039056tmp
/root/retrofit/retrofit/target/surefire/surefire_02232907551688610770tmp
```

Note the `-javaagent` option added by JaCoCo. If you would like to have a look at the whole logs issued by `mvn clean test`, you can find them here: https://pastebin.com/kUtLtyjw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using JaCoCo you want to ensure that syntethic fields and methods are not processed by your own code as JaCoCo uses them to collect the coverage statistics. Luckily both `Field` and `Method` have the `isSynthetic()` method.

```
public static Method onlyMethod(Class c) {
  return Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredMethods())
    .filter(m -> !m.isSynthetic())
    .reduce((a, b) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException("More than one method declared.");
    })
    .get();
}
```